# How does abstract method of predefined interface like Connection, Statement etc. perform some task without having body?

Tags: java, interface

There are many predefined interfaces in java like `ResultSet`, `Connection`, `Statement` etc.An Interface can have only abstract methods (unimplemented methods).So why do we use there methods without defining them first.

for example in following code of jdbc

```
public class JDBCSample {

public static void main( String args[]) {

String connectionURL = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/movies;
user=java;password=samples";`

try {

    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");  


    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection (connectionURL);


    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();


    ResultSet rs = stmd.executeQuery("select moviename, releasedate from movies");

    while (rs.next())
        {....do something.....}
}catch (SQLException e)
 {e.printStackTrace();}
catch (Exception e) 
{ e.printStackTrace();}}
```

here are we calling abstract `createStatement()` and `executeQuery()` method of `Connection` and `Statement` interface? If yes then how an abstract method(method without body) can perform some task?

Comment: +1 as my question, see link in your selected answer, is the same, but yours is better formed. Leading to a better answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `DriverManager.getConnection`, it returns an instance of `org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection`, which is a class that implements the `java.sql.Connection` interface.

`Jdbc4Connection` has a method body for `createStatement` that returns an instance of `org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Statement`, which is a class that implements the `java.sql.Statement` interface.

`Jdbc4Statement` has a method body for `executeQuery` which returns an instance of `org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4ResultSet`, which is a class that implements the `java.sql.ResultSet` interface.

Comment: +1 answered my Question here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12277574/how-do-objects-of-interface-being-returned-have-thier-methods-declared perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Call:

```
System.out.println(con.getClass());
```

and notice that the actual object is not of `Connection` type. This is called *polymorphism*. Simply put `DriverManager.getConnection()` returns *something* that implements `Connection`. You are invoking methods on that *something*. This is an advantage of *polymorphism* - the JDBC driver can later decide to change *something* and as long as it implements `Connection`, your code couldn't care less.

Straightforward example:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.size();  //calling abstract method?!? No!
```

In the example above we are actually calling `ArrayList.size()`.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling methods of classes that are implementing this methods.

`DriverManager.getConnection` returns you concrete implementation of `Connection` interface, and you don't need to know what exact class is returned. It's main idea of having interfaces.

Comment: thanx for reply. But i am confused whether `createStatement()` and `executeQuery()` methods of `Connection` and `Statement` interface is called or some other class's method is called. I would appreciate if you elaborate this.

Answer (score 0):

By the time you're actually *calling* something, the reference you have is to an instance of a concrete subclass which provides all the bodies. The point is that you (as the client) don't need to care what that implementation is - it's provided for you by `DriverManager` (etc). All you need to care about is that it's "something which implements the given interface" or "something which extends the abstract class".

A simpler example would be to use the collection types:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
doSomething(list);

...

public static void doSomething(List<String> list) {
    // Act on the list
}
```

Here, `doSomething` doesn't need to know that we used an `ArrayList<E>` - it could operate on *any* kind of `List<String>`... but as you can see, as it happens we create an instance of `ArrayList<E>`, which is a concrete class.

Answer (score 0):

The particular implementation of the interface you are using, in this case `DriverManager`, returns a concrete class that implements the abstract methods of the interface.

As you pointed out, the interface only *declares* the methods that the concrete implementation must provide. The actual implementation class provides the bodies of the those methods.

The `DriverManager` class and its package provide the missing pieces, returning concrete classes that have complete method bodies. You interact with those classes on your client code side only through the interface, however. The implementation details of the concrete classes are effectively hidden from view.