# How do objects of interfaces being returned have their methods declared

Tags: java, interface

This feels like a silly question, but it aggravates me as I don't understand where the methods are declared.  In my code I can do things like (obviously this is a bit pseudo code)

```
ResultSet rs = DB.getConnection.sendSQL(select * from [table])
```

I understand that the sending of the SQL returns a 'result set' and although a 'ResultSet' is only an interface the returned object implements that interface.

My question is how does the returned object implement that interface?  From what I read interface can only define a method signature, not a complete function.

So where are the functions defined? Obviously not in the ResultSet interface!  Am I correct in understanding that this the job of the database Driver? (I think I may have just answered my own question).

Can I write an interface with a fully functioning method? Will any implementing classes then automatically implement that method, or do I just overwrite it with a call to 'super' or something?

I just found this other question on SO
[How does abstract method of predefined interface like Connection, Statement etc. perform some task without having body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811265/how-does-abstract-method-of-predefined-interface-like-connection-statement-etc?rq=1)
which is a perfect duplicate, but much bette formulated. And a great answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes that implement an interface are responsible for declaring all of the methods in the interface, and where appropriate implementing the internal logic for those methods.

The interface is essentially saying "You have to provide functionality for this, but I don't care *how* you do that. You just have to take inputs of these types and provide output of this type." The class is where you implement how you get from the inputs to the outputs.

Comment: I kinda understood that I just suddenly realised that I was getting a resultSet object from the result of sending the SQL to the DB. So I wondered where the ResultSet object was being created, and if the interface was able to determine some of the functionality of the methods. This also explains why there are often abstract classes that implement an interface, with all the method bodies being 'empty'.

Comment: @DaveM You're not getting a `ResultSet` object, you're getting an object that's an instance of a class that implements the `ResultSet` interface.

Comment: So in effect I get 'part of' an object. So my called object may have a member that implements the interface, or may implment it itself. If the called object implements the interface (and maybe others also - here the statement object may implement metaData as well as result set), when the 'object implementing the interface' is returned I guess I only have access to those methods of the interface, and not any others that are in the called class, is that correct.

Comment: @DaveM Yes, that's correct. The compiler only knows that it's working with an instance of some class that implements `ResultSet` so it can only guarantee that the methods defined in that interface are present in that class.

Comment: Cool, so the JDBC driver is handling the whole 'result set' object creation thing, and the compiler does its stuff making sure I only get access to those methods. One day I really must have a look at the code of a JDBC driver ! I've given you +1 for patience. And as your comments have lead me to understand better how the compiler and driver work in unison i'm giving yours as the correct answer. But I recomend anyone else to also look at the link in my question. Its question is better, and the answer equally usefull.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is how does the returned object implement that interface?

```
class ResultSetImpl implements ResultSet { ... }
```

> From what I read interface can only define a method signature, not a complete function. So where are the functions defined? obviously not in the ResultSet interface!

In the returned object. In the dots ;-)

This is *very* basic Java.

Comment: So ResultSetImpl{...} is in the database driver somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Let's take the following scenario:

We have an interface:

```
public interface Expendable(){
  public void expend();
}
```

And a class that implements it:

```
public class MyClass implements Expendable(){
  public void expend(){
//Do something
}
}
```

And another class returns in a method an object that implements our interface:

```
public class OtherClass(){
  public Expendable myMethod(){
   return new MyClass();
}
}
```

`OtherClass myMethod` returns an object (we don't know what `Class` it is just by looking at the method return type) that implements `Expendable` interface. The current Expend method is defined in the actual class myMethod is returning. In this case, the method who is invoked if you do

```
new OtherClass.myMethod().expend();
```

is MyClass expend method.

Comment: So the database driver is implementing the interface somewhere in the inner workings of the driver. The more I think about this the more strange / abstract it feels. Probably because I rarely write interfaces, and all but never return objects that implement them ! Is this bad, or just unusual?

Comment: I recommend you to read more about Interfaces: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/interfaces.html